# Recyceler View on device rotation replication

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

In My Application, there is Recycler view in fragment

When I follow following steps Its got duplicated in Nexus
 6 5.1.1 device
1)Change device orientation to landscape
2)Lock the device
3)change device orientation to portrait
4) unlock device
Now for 1 sec There is replication of view

I have `setRetainInstance = true` in fragment

and

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(getContentFrame(),fragment,fragment.getClass().getName())
                        .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
                        .commit();
```

for adding fragment

[image: before rotation] [image: after rotation]

Comment: what about recyclerview intilization code? where you put it in the fragment?

Comment: @Ajay_Reddy  onCreateView

Comment: just add check in oncreate of your activity in which you are adding fragment. Add fragment only if the savedInstance is not equals null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 things:

onSaveInstanceState 
onRestoreInstanceState

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you're adding the fragment again, although it already exists.

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(getContentFrame(),fragment,fragment.getClass().getName())
                    .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
                    .commit();
```

I'm guessing you're calling this twice (once initially and once after orientation change), so your fragment gets added twice. Depending on how you implemented this, either just add a check just before this call `if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YourFragment.class.getName()) == null)` our check in acitivity `onCreate()` if `(savedInstanceState == null)`.